# Regex Negative Lookbehind to Negate a Full Capture

Tags: regex

I'm want to detect numbers that don't have letters before them.

example:

**ignore**: covid19

**accept**: 19

I have this regex: `(?<![a-z])(\d+)` that uses a negative lookbehind to check if there's letters b4 the numbers, and if so, don't capture.

The problem is that if I type covid1 then it is ignored as expected, but if I type covid19 or covid1+[any more numbers] it doesn't get ignored.

How do I do a negative lookbehind that negates the whole capture following it?

Comment: What about `20test` or `$$19`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex was very close. Although with some changes if you want only the numbers to matched i.e. it doesn't has any letters associated with it.

```
(?<![\S])(\b\d+\b)
     ^^   ^^   ^^ changes
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

> **`\b`** - Represents a [word-boundary.](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)
>
> **`\d+`** - Matches digit[0-9] **one or more times**.
>
> **`\S`** - Matches any non-whitespace character.
>
> **`(?<![\S])`** - Negative look-behind asserts that non-whitespace characters should not be matched before and after the **1st capturing group**.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

You can find the demo in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/aJJHOP/5)